# Issues with MouseControl in a different fxml using javafx

Tags: javafx, rotation, mouseevent

I am sorry to ask this silly question. I am unable to solve it and I need guidance.

In my application I start my main java code with menu  as

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("MONC GUI :: Abhijit Bhattacharyya");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MoncGUI.class.getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
    rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();        
    //Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
    rootScene = new Scene(rootLayout);
    primaryStage.setScene(rootScene);                
    RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setMainApp(this);  
    primaryStage.show();
}
    ......
```

Then I opt to go to a particular menu page by opening another fxml in the main class as

```
public void GeomStart() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MoncGUI.class.getResource("Geom.fxml"));
        AnchorPane geomPage = (AnchorPane)loader.load();            
        rootLayout.setCenter(geomPage);   
        GeomController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMyScene(rootScene);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(" Problem in loading geometry set");
        Logger.getLogger(MoncGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The `geom.fxml` is associated with geomController.java which puts a primitive geometric form on the screen and I want it to be rotated.  I find mouseHandler code in the internet which should be activated as `screen` is passed.

I am confused which screen should I pass. Is it the root screen initiated by the main class at the start or I need to define a new screen locally here in this controller.  I tried with a screen local to this controller yet the code handle is not passed to MouseHandler code.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to pass the scene arround at all. Inside your controller you have access to the nodes which you have defined in your FXML file. Once this file is loaded and you have attached its root node to the scene graph you can get the scene by calling the .getScene() method of any of these nodes.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  As a part of this question, I like to ask you a related question. This new GeoController needs a Stage beside scene to control Mouse for 3D rotation and also for Camera. I had an idea that stage is once defined as Root.  Do I need to bring that Root Stage or I need define local Stage?